# Solution to a system of nonlinear equations using convex conjugate of log sum exp

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, convex-analysis

I need to prove the following result:

There exists a unique solution to the system of equations

$$\alpha = \frac{I^T(\gamma e^{I\beta})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\gamma_ie^{(I\beta)_i}}$$ 
if and only if $\alpha = I^T \lambda$ ($\lambda \in (\mathbb{R}_+^*)^n$)

with $\alpha \in ]0,1[^p$ (a vector), $\gamma^T \in (\mathbb{R}_+^*)^n$ and $I$ a binary matrix (filled with 0 and 1 only) in $\mathcal{M}_{n\times p}$({0,1}). Of course $I^T$ denotes the transpose matrix if $I$. And we are in the case $n>p$. $I$ is a matrix of full rank.

$I^T(\gamma e^{I\beta})$ is a matrix-vector multiplication with $\gamma e^{I\beta}$ having components $\gamma_i e^{(I\beta)_i}$.

I want to use the convex conjugate of the log-sum-exp function to solve the problem but I am not comfortable enough in this field to write the right proof! Please help !!!

Here is an example using this approach

[exemple using the convex conjugate with log-sum-exp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXaaA.png)

It's possible that this result comes from a theorem about composite convex conjugate. 
See
[A note on the Legendre-Fenchel transform of convex composite functions](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~jbhu/A_note_on_the_LF_transform.pdf)